# How to scale a value within each subset of elements?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to rescale the text of each `.totalInput` within each `.subgroup` and pass it into the `width` attribute, how can I do it?

```js
$('div.subgroup').each(function(index, element) {
  var maxLength = Math.max.apply(Math, $(".totalInput", this).map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get());
  $('.totalInput').each(function(index, element) {
    var tot = element;
    $(element).siblings(".facet-percentage").width(parseInt(($(element).text() / maxLength)) + '%');

  });
});
```

```css
span {display:inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='group'>
  <div class='subgroup'>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>10</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>20</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>30</span>

  </div>
  <div class='subgroup'>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>50</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>100</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>70</span>

  </div>

</div>
```

Such that the output of the 1st subgroup would become:

```
<div class='subgroup'>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width='33%'></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>10</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width='66%'></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>20</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width='100%'></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>30</span>

  </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to set the width attribute of every `.facet-percentage` to the value of the first `.totalInput` that comes after it?

Comment: If you are depending on width, make sure you have `span {display:inline-block`}`

Comment: It should take the maximum of the set of the 3 of them and rescale each value. So for example the first set would be `10/30`,`20/30`, `30/30` and rescaled in percent.

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks, updated

Comment: Your explanation is hard to follow. Maybe you can draw the expected result in ASCII art?

Comment: @Tomalak Sorry, I added an example, does it look clearer now?

Comment: Note that setting the width attribute on a `span` element doesn't do anything; you'd need to set `style.width` if you expect the actual width to change.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do what you want:

```js
$('div.subgroup').each(function () {
  var maxLength = Math.max.apply(Math, $(this).find(".totalInput").map(function() {
    return +$(this).text();
  }).get());

  $(this).find('.facet-percentage').css('width', function () {
    return (100 * +$(this).next().text() / maxLength) + '%';
  }).html("&nbsp;");
});
```

```css
.subgroup {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
}
.subgroup > span {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.facet-percentage {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='group'>
  <div class='subgroup'>
    <span class='facet-percentage'></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>10</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage'></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>20</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage'></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>30</span>
  </div>
  <div class='subgroup'>
    <span class='facet-percentage'></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>50</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage'></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>100</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage'></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>70</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the CSS properties I've changed to make it look nice in the sample. Read up on box-sizing and the difference between `display: inline` (the default for `<span>`) and `display: block`. Simply use `<div>` if you want block elements anyway.

Also, note that jQuery can modify a certain property (in this case css width) in one go with a callback function. This is handy to keep in mind, it works the same way with other jQuery DOM manipulation functions.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you need this:

```js
$('div.subgroup').each(function(index, element) {
  var maxLength = Math.max.apply(Math, $(".totalInput", this).map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get());
  
  $(this).children('.totalInput').each(function(index, element) {
    var tot = element;
//console.log(parseInt($(tot).text() / maxLength*100));

$(element).prev(".facet-percentage").css('width',parseInt($(tot).text()/maxLength*100)+'%');

  });  
 

});
```

```css
span.facet-percentage {display:block; background:red;margin-bottom:10px;height:10px;}
.subgroup {
  width:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='group'>
  <div class='subgroup'>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>10</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>20</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>30</span>

  </div>
  <div class='subgroup'>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>50</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>100</span>
    <span class='facet-percentage' width=''></span>
    <span class='totalInput'>70</span>

  </div>

</div>
```

So, you need to target childrens of each subgroup, and to target prev element of current total span, and multiply with 100...